# Does braintree void transaction immediately releases pending charge on customer credit card?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, hibernate, transactions, braintree

I am implementing braintree payment gateway in one of my projects. The scenario is such that I need to verify first whether the user have sufficient balance to process the order successfully or not. If yes then I do the order processing and if not then no order is executed for processing.

Is there a way to verify before initiating the transaction that user has sufficient balance or not? I know this can only be done while carrying out the transaction but this is not what I want.

In my order there are items from multiple sellers in the basket and these sellers are my submerchants in my dashboard of braintree account. What I want is that when customer tries to place an order having items from multiple sellers then a separate transaction should be created for each seller in user basket and sent to submerchant bank account. But the problem is that without executing a transaction I cannot know whether the user's credit card will have sufficient funds to execute all the submerchants order successfully thus completing the whole order.

For example: 
A user has added items worth $1000 in his basket from 3 sellers. Basket has seller 1 products worth $300 and seller 2 items worth $300 and seller 3 items worth $400 thus totaling $1000. But the user has only $700 funds. 
As 'place order' button will be hit by customer then a transaction($300) will be carried out sucessfully for seller 1 and second transaction for seller 2($300) will be carried out successfully but the third transaction would fail because of insufficient balance.

I want that either all the transactions should be completed or not transaction should be done at all. 
For that I need to know user account balance before executing the transaction but that can only be determined during transaction. 
What should I do?

I thought of one solution that first I make 'Authorization' transaction of $1000 and if that returns true indicating the user has sufficient balance then I immediately do a void transaction of 'Authorization' transaction and do my sub transactions.

But as Authorization transactions puts the funds on hold I want to know whether the void transaction would immediately remove the hold from user funds or it would take time.

Any suggestions for this scenario? What should I do or where I am going wrong?

Comment: I work at Braintree. It's currently a holiday in the US, but your best bet is still to email our support team at support@braintreepayments.com. You should get a response on Monday.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to  do with programming as defined in the FAQ